# Unity Photon Doesnt Sync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Hey guys I want to make a multiplayer game with unity. But I cannot sync players.

I use Photon Transform View and Photon View. I have attached Photon Transform View to Photon View but still it doesnt work.

**This is my player movement code:**

```csharp
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using Photon.Realtime;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Movement : Photon.MonoBehaviour
    {
        joystick griliVAl;
        Animator animasyon;
        int Idle = Animator.StringToHash("Idle");
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            animasyon = GetComponent<Animator>();
            griliVAl = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<joystick>();
        }
    
        public void OnButton()
        {
            animasyon.Play("attack_01");
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
             float x = griliVAl.griliv.x;
             float y = griliVAl.griliv.y;
             animasyon.SetFloat("Valx", x);
             animasyon.SetFloat("Valy", y);
    
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(griliVAl.griliv*5);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position += griliVAl.griliv * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

It will be mobile game. So that these griliVal value is joysticks circle.

But can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If by whatever means it doesn't work, try using `OnPhotonSerializeView()`.

Here is what you can put

```csharp
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.isWriting)
        stream.SendNext(transform.position);
    }
    else if (stream.isReading)
    {
        transform.position = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

It is really similar to using Photon transform View, but you are manually synchronizing the player's position.

Check if `PhotonView` is attached to the same gameobject the script is in for `OnPhotonSerializeView` to work.

Don't forget to add **IPunObservable** in your code

```csharp
public class Movement : Photon.MonoBehaviour, IPunObservable
```